# revalidatePath doesn't work on fetch with headers()

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, next.js13

I am using `NextJS 13.5`.
When I want to perform revalidation I get

```
TypeError: fetch failed Cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header. code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'.
```

This has a direct correlation with `headers()` because when I remove the `headers()` call, fetch runs without any problem. However, I cannot remove `headers()` because it verifies the user's session in the API, which is extremely important. Of course, the problem only occurs during revalidation, when loading the page everything works without a problem.

Below is my code.

Page component

```js
import StartQuiz from "./startQuiz/StartQuiz";
import QuizGame from "./quizGame/PlayQuiz";
import { headers } from "next/headers";

const PlayQuiz = async ({ params }: { params: {id: string} }) => {
  const { id } = params;

  const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/play/quiz/${id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers(),
    cache: 'no-cache',
  });

  const quiz = await response.json();

  return (
    <div>
      {
        quiz.errorId === 101 ? (
          <StartQuiz 
            quizSlug={quiz.quizSlug}
            id={id}
          />
        ) : (
          <QuizGame
            id={id}
          />
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default PlayQuiz;
```

Revalidate function

```js
"use server"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

const updateQuizData = () => {
  revalidatePath('/(play)/play/quiz/[id]', 'page');
}

export default updateQuizData;
```

Function that activates revalidation

```js
const handleStart = async () => {
    toast.promise(
      async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/play/quiz/${id}/start`, {
          method: 'POST',
          cache: 'no-cache',
        });
  
        const quiz = await response.json();
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(quiz.message || 'Something went wrong');
        }

        updateQuizData();
      },
      {
        pending: 'Starting quiz...',
        success: 'Get ready!',
        error: {
          render: ({ data }: { data?: { message: string } }) => data?.message || 'Something went wrong',
        },
      }
    );
  };
```

I tried throwing out the headers.